# How to stop overwriting an array in foreach

Tags: php, arrays, regex, foreach

I'm trying to create a multi dimensional array but the inner part keeps using the last value of the array in the foreach.

I'm using PHP 7.3 with Laravel 5.8. I've tried doing a foreach for the area then a foreach for the location and inside that do a foreach for the information.
The regex I'm using is:

```
// Define regex for each of the required fields
$location_regex = '/----(.*)-----/m';
$total_regex = '/^.*\bTotal\b.*/m';
$age_regex = '/Age         (?:DAYS       (\d+))/m';
// Perform the regex
preg_match_all($location_regex, $message, $locations, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
preg_match_all($age_regex, $message, $ageMatches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
preg_match_all($total_regex, $message, $totalMatches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
```

Then of course the $ageMatches and $totalMatches are returned as arrays.

I'm using regex to get values out of the following plain text email:

```
"""
        ELY FARM
      THE ADDRESS
  BW8010 2.55  UNIT 1

Logged   03 JUN 19 23:59

     SUMMARY REPORT

----UNIT 1  PERCH 1-----
     House 1, Pen 1

Age         DAYS       7
Total               3997
Average     GMS       64
Deviation   GMS       14
Evenness    %         29
C.V.        %       21.9
Daily gain  GMS        9

----UNIT 1  PERCH 2-----
     House 1, Pen 2

Age         DAYS       7
Total               3849
Average     GMS       73
Deviation   GMS       17
Evenness    %         29
C.V.        %       23.3
Daily gain  GMS        9

----UNIT 1  PERCH 9-----
     House 3, Pen 3

Age         DAYS       7
Total               3614
Average     GMS       67
Deviation   GMS       16
Evenness    %         23
C.V.        %       23.9
Daily gain  GMS        8
```

The data I have is

```
    // Go through each message
            foreach ($aMessage as $oMessage) {
                // Get address from email subject
                $address = $oMessage->getSubject(true);

                // Add the address to an array
                $email_data = array($address);

                // Add the sub location to each address in the array
                foreach ($locations as $location) {
                    $email_data[$address][$location[1]] = array();

                    // Add the data to the sub location in the array
                    foreach ($ageMatches as $ageIndex => $age) {
                        $email_data[$address][$location[1]]['Age'] = $age[1];
                    }
                    foreach ($totalMatches as $totalIndex => $total) {
                        $total['Total'] = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $total);
                        $email_data[$address][$location[1]]['Total'] = $total['Total'][0];
                    }
                }
            dd($email_data);
            }
```

The current output is:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "Ely Farm"
  "Ely Farm" => array:10 [▼
    "UNIT 1  PERCH 1" => array:7 [▼
      "Age" => "7"
      "Total" => "3614"
      "Average" => "67"
      "Deviation" => "16"
      "Evenness" => "23"
      "C.V." => "..23.9"
      "Daily Gain" => "8"
    ]
    "UNIT 1  PERCH 2" => array:7 [▼
      "Age" => "7"
      "Total" => "3614"
      "Average" => "67"
      "Deviation" => "16"
      "Evenness" => "23"
      "C.V." => "..23.9"
      "Daily Gain" => "8"
    ]
```

I'm expecting to get:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "Ely Farm"
  "Ely Farm" => array:10 [▼
    "UNIT 1  PERCH 1" => array:7 [▼
      "Age" => "7"
      "Total" => "3997"
      "Average" => "64"
      "Deviation" => "14"
      "Evenness" => "29"
      "C.V." => "..21.9"
      "Daily Gain" => "9"
    ]
    "UNIT 1  PERCH 2" => array:7 [▼
      "Age" => "7"
      "Total" => "3849"
      "Average" => "73"
      "Deviation" => "17"
      "Evenness" => "29"
      "C.V." => "..23.9"
      "Daily Gain" => "9"
    ]
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I'm expecting to get different values for each Age, Total etc... At the moment it's picking the last value of each array.

Comment: why are you using array index 1 everywhere

Comment: @shihab The output of `dd($location);` inside the foreach is `array:2 [▼
  0 => "----UNIT 1  PERCH 1-----"
  1 => "UNIT 1  PERCH 1"
]` so I want to use $location[1] the same for Age, total, etc...

Comment: This is really hard to answer without some proper sample input data.

Comment: Where are $ageMatches and $totalMatches declared? I assume that they should be dinamically created inside the foreach loop. The way you are doing it now, you fill every element of your new array with the same values.

Comment: The $ageMatches and $totalMatches are done through regex I've added the regex in the question

Comment: Well `$totalMatches` is not mentioned in the example code

Comment: Sorry, I've added it in. I did `$totalMatches` as the example because the data is different. I basically do the same thing but slightly different regex to get what I want

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your regular expression is not extracting all data. Only the last occurrence of the matched data is being returned.

Your regular expressions are using 'm' modifier. This modifier indicates multi line input. But the regular expression needs to indicate the start and end of the input using the '^' and '$' characters. See the documentation for [Regular Expression Pattern modifiers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

Comment: No if I do `dd($totalMatches);` just above the foreach for messages I get: `array:9 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    0 => "Total               3997"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    0 => "Total               3849 `